# Android use both background image and background color

Tags: android, background-image, background-color, android-drawable

I am used to writing things in html and one of the things I commonly do is make partially transparent patterns so that I can just change the background color instead of having to make a separate image for each color. I was wondering if there was something similar I can do on the Android. Right now I have a small image (5x5 pixels) that I repeat using an xml file in the drawables folder. It is used in the background of a scroll view which right now has a linear layout inside. Switching to a relative layout so that I can have an imageview would require a lot of programming changes so I'm wondering if there isn't an easier way.

Everywhere I have looked for a solution, the answers are a year or two old and they say to use two separate views, but it just seems like this is something that should have been implemented by now. And yes from a programming standpoint changing colors is just as easy as changing images, but it would just be a lot easier to be able to change the color instead of having to make an image for each new color.

Comment: have you tried wrapping the whole layout in a FrameLayout, and setting the background colour of the FrameLayout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [Layer List drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList) to achieve this. First add the color, then the bitmap.

If you prefer to create it programmatically instead of via resource files, use the [LayerDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html) class.

Comment: Oooh this is exatly what I was looking for, and then it looks like I can just use `setDrawableByLayerId()` to switch out the colors. Thanks, this never popped up in any of my searches.

Answer (score 0):

Below code for black:-

```
<color name="black">#000000</color>
```

Now if i want to use opacity than you can use below code :-

```
<color name="black">#99000000</color>
```

and below for opacity code:-

Hex Opacity Values

100% — FF
95% — F2
90% — E6
85% — D9
80% — CC
75% — BF
70% — B3
65% — A6
60% — 99
55% — 8C
50% — 80
45% — 73
40% — 66
35% — 59
30% — 4D
25% — 40
20% — 33
15% — 26
10% — 1A
5% — 0D
0% — 00

Comment: I understand colors and opacity, its using color and partially transparent images in the background of the same view.